# ADF Web activity get access token with Post API using System Assigned managed identity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-purview

I want to use ADF , web activity to get the access token from
https://login.windows.net/**********/oauth2/token

using the system assigned managed identity from ADF

resource is

https://purview.azure.net

How is the request body should be ? how is the header should be ?

Comment: please share what you have tried and error you are getting.

Comment: {"grant_type": "client_credentials"} as body    and  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded as header

Comment: anyone has the idea ?

Comment: @mytabi Any luck on this? I'm also looking for options to obtain an access token with ADF Web activity using a Post API and managed identity.

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow below steps:**

**Step 1:** Create  a web activity to get the Access Token from ADF

- Add your URL: `https://login..../<Tenant ID>/oauth2/token`

[image]

- **Method :** POST
- **Body:** `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&resource=https://purview.azure.net/`
- **Header:** `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- **Authentication:** `System Assigned Managed Identity`
- **Resource**: `https://purview.azure.net/`

[image]

**Step2:** Create Set variable :

- Add dynamic content ->  `@activity('Web1').output.access_token`

[image]

**Response**

[image]

Comment: If you're already submitting a `client_secret` in the POST body, then what is the "Authentication: System Assigned Managed Identity" still for?

Comment: This shows how to do it with Client id and secret. This doesn't really answer the question which is related to managed identity.